# how to avoid duplicate values in kendo autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, filter, kendo-ui

I used a `kendo grid` also over the grid has a kendo autocomplete control. The grid row contains a column has duplicate values. while searching, how to distinct the column value?

```
var d1 = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
$("#acProjName").kendoAutoComplete({
              dataSource: d1,
              dataTextField: "ProjectName",
              filter: "startswith",
              placeholder: "Project Name",
              change: ProjectSearch
             );
```

thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter your array before giving it as a DataSource (or creating a DataSource based on it) to the AutoComplete widget.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
  { "make": "Audi", "model": "A1" },
  { "make": "Audi", "model": "A2" },
  { "make": "Audi", "model": "A3" },
  { "make": "Audi", "model": "A4" },
  { "make": "Saab", "model": "S500" }
];

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: data
                },
                columns: [{
                    field: "make",
                    title: "make"

                }, {
                    field: "model",
                    title: "model"
                }]
            });

            makesDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(),
                group: { field: "make", value: "make" }
            });



            var makes = $("#makes").kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "Select make...",
                dataTextField: "value",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: makesDatasource
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="grid">
        </div>
        <div id="makes">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Due to some reason Autocomplete control is not working in my system, so I have provided demo related to DropdownList control.  Please check datasource and datatextfield in the dropdownlist control. You have to add same property in autocomplete control.

Let me know if any concern.